PDF using the integral intermediate value theorem and epsilon definition
I am trying a different proof concept using the intermediate value theorem to show that for $2$ continuous,independent random variables $X,Y$, then :
$U=X+Y$ and $$ f_{U}\left(t\right)=\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(t-y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy$$
I know the standard proof with derivatives or using the characteristic function, I just want to know why this doesn't work
Let $ f_{U}\left(t\right)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}P\left(t\le U\le t+\varepsilon\right)$
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}P\left(t\le X+Y\le t+\varepsilon\right)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int\int_{t\le x+y\le t+\varepsilon}f_{XY}\left(x,y\right)dxdy=$$
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int\int_{t\le x+y\le t+\varepsilon}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dxdy=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int\limits _{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\left(\int\limits _{x=t-y}^{x=t-y+\varepsilon}f_{X}\left(x\right)dx\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy= $$
At this point we can move the limit inside, as it doesn't matter for the outer integral.
$$ \int\limits _{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\left(\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int\limits _{x=t-y}^{x=t-y+\varepsilon}f_{X}\left(x\right)dx\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy $$
Now here I want to use the intermediate value theorem which says that for some $c \in [a,b]:$
$$ \int\limits _{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx=\left(b-a\right)\cdot f\left(c\right) $$
In our case, because $\varepsilon$ approaches $0$, that $c$ can just be $t-y$ and so :
$$ \int\limits _{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\left(\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int\limits _{x=t-y}^{x=t-y+\varepsilon}f_{X}\left(x\right)dx\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy\approx\int\limits _{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}\left(\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\varepsilon f_{X}\left(t-y\right)\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy $$
So basically I have almost what I needed to prove, except I have another multiplication by an $\varepsilon$. Where did I go wrong with it?

Shouldn’t your first limit, the one for $f_U(t) =\cdots$, be divided by $\varepsilon$?

Yes in the first equality you should have something like $f_U(t)dt$ on the left hand side.

Why is that? Intuitively, it's just the probability $P(U=t)$ if we go by generalizing the discrete case

Ok using the same arguments with the I.I.V.T we can see that :
$$ P\left(t\le U\le t+\varepsilon\right)=\int\limits {t}^{t+\varepsilon}f{U}\left(u\right)du\approx\varepsilon f_{U}\left(t\right) $$
and so really $$ f_{U}\left(t\right)=\frac{P\left(t\le U\le t+\varepsilon\right)}{\varepsilon} $$
I guess thats where my mistake comes from.
Thank you good sirs.
